# Using Eulers formula

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to figure out how 
\begin{equation*}
e^{i(-1+i\sqrt{3})}=e^{-\sqrt{3}} (cos(1)-i sin(1))??
\end{equation*}
I know that Euler's formula states that 
\begin{equation*}
e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)
\end{equation*}
but surely that would mean in this case $x=-1+i\sqrt{3}$? Can someone please elaborate. Many thanks.

Comment: **HINT**: $$i(-1+i\sqrt{3})=-i+i^2\sqrt{3}=-i-\sqrt{3}$$and:$$e^{a+b}=e^{a}\times e^{b}$$

Comment: In addition to Mufasa's hint you also need to know that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are even and odd functions respectively; i.e. $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: I added parentheses to make $e^{i(-1 + i\sqrt{3})}$ come out right!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$$ e^{i(-1+i\sqrt{3})} = e^{-i-\sqrt{3}} = e^{-\sqrt{3}}e^{-i} = e^{-\sqrt{3}}\left(\cos{1}-i\sin{1}\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

As Shayan says,

$e^{i(-1 + i \sqrt{3})} = e^{-\sqrt{3} - i} = e^{-\sqrt{3}} e^{-i} = e^{-\sqrt{3}}(\cos(1) - i\sin(1)); \tag{1}$

it is also true that

$e^{i(-1 + i \sqrt{3})} = \cos(-1 + i \sqrt{3}) + i\sin(-1 + i \sqrt{3}), \tag{2}$

since for *any* $z \in \Bbb C$,

$e^{iz} = \cos z + i \sin z; \tag{3}$

in (3), $e^{iz}$, $\cos z$, and $\sin z$ are understood to be *complex analytic* (*holomorphic*) functions; (3) may be verified for $z \in \Bbb C$ *via* the power series expansions of these three entire functions about $0$:

$e^{iz} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(iz)^n}{n!} = 1 + iz + i^2 \dfrac{z^2}{2} + i^3 \dfrac{z^3}{6} + \ldots = 1 + iz - \dfrac{z^2}{2} - i\dfrac{z^3}{6} + \ldots$
$= (1 - \dfrac{z^2}{2} + \ldots) + i(z - \dfrac{z^3}{6} + \ldots) = \cos z + i \sin z, \tag{4}$

etc. etc. etc.